# Why is contract deploying, but giving an error on console

Tags: web3js, nodejs, solc

So I'm using ganache client and deploying the contract. I can see the contract on ganache and also the transaction. But on the console I'm getting following error:

```
    ...
    code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
  error: {
    message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas',
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas\n' +
      '    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:12745)\n' +
      '    at Miner.<anonymous> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:36703)\n' +
      '    at async Miner.<anonymous> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:35116)\n' +
      '    at async Miner.mine (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:39680)\n' +
      '    at async Blockchain.mine (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:60063)\n' +
      '    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n' +
      '    at async TransactionPool.emit (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache/node_modules/emittery/index.js:303:3)',
    code: -32000,
    name: 'RuntimeError',
    data: {
      hash: '0xa3b80827fe7a2e42047cd5d2dcca6872485976d599ea2fd498fa19f3ec92069a',
      programCounter: 37,
      result: '0xa3b80827fe7a2e42047cd5d2dcca6872485976d599ea2fd498fa19f3ec92069a',
      reason: null,
      message: 'out of gas'
    }
  },
  payload: {
    method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
...
```

My deploy.js code

```
async function main() {
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x025fefdecd13d6d2929b75f114aee8830b2977f886b1b733870d554596ef0efd",
    provider
  );

  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin");
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);

  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({
    gasLimit: 3000000,
  });

}
```

I'm following a youtube video from about 2 years ago. I changed a few things on the code, like adding the gasLimit (it throw another error if it wasn't included), but this error I can't solve. I also tried to downgrade both ethers and solc, but it is still not working. It is strange that it gives an gas error, but is still deploying the contract. Because of that I can't go further with the course.

My ethers version: 6.9.2
My solc version: 0.8.23-fixed

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the error, but actually, I didn't get any such error can you specify the ethers version, I'm using v6+

You can check the code also, there is not much difference -

```js
async function main() {
    //...
    
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, byteCode, wallet);
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({ gasLimit: 3000000 });
    await contract.waitForDeployment();
    const contractAdr = await contract.getAddress();
    console.log(`Contract deployed to ${contractAdr}`);
    
    //...
}
```

[image]

As you've mentioned the contract is deploying successfully, are you sure about it?
Also, it's not mandatory to specify the gasLimit, cause I've tried deploying contract without it and it worked.

Comment: That is really strange :D. I just tried it with your different code, but I'm still getting same error. The error also says: "shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'". Do you also used Ganache? Can it be something about that?

Comment: What is your ethers and solc version?

Comment: As I stated the ethers version I'm using is v6+

Comment: @MySti Yes I'm using Ganache too, so the issue is not related to Ganache I think it's somehow related to Ethers.

Comment: I tried a few different versions of ethers, but its the same error every time